# Rating Items From Ratings of Random Sets

Tags: rating, recommendation-engine

I'm looking for an algorithm to determine ratings or tags for items when my own input is giving the user random sets of these items and letting them tell me which ratings or tags are within that set. For example, they might say if a set of images contains any "good" photos and out of several random sets and I then want to determine which photos are good. Now, I also can adjust the sets of items I give the user to those that would help me refine the knowledge of these items. So, if a given item was in sets marked both "good" and "bad", the system would try to place it in sets of known good items, perhaps, to determine if the user now says that set has a bad item, and I know the one with unsure status is the "bad" item. Does this make sense?

Comment: Are you trying to associate features of the images with tags or ratings, or are merely trying to determine the tag or rating of a given item given how they've scored in a variety of groups?  If it is the second one, you can do a lot better than a neural network, and I can give an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use an artificial neural network; see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network). There are lots of links at this [FAQ](http://ftp://ftp.sas.com/pub/neural/FAQ.html).

Comment: There are a lot of different things I could feed into an ANN to try and get good results here, so this answer sounds interesting but doesn't given enough details to really give a direction.

Comment: 1. Give "the user random sets of these items and letting them tell me which ratings or tags are within that set."
2. Train the ANN with each pair of "ratings or tags" and "items." E.g., if the set had 4 images, & user said "weird" and "pretty," train the ANN with 8 pairs ("weird","pretty") * 4 imgs.